# Significance and meaning of Krom bija mantra

Tags: mantras, goddess, devi

There are some moolamantras, which involves `krom` . 
Whats the significance of this bija mantra. Does it represents any Goddess or any God. and the way, `klim` bija mantra represents `attraction`, does `krom` represents anything? if we chant the moolamantras of Goddessess/God which has `krom` bija, what kind of benefits we are getting.

Comment: While checking mantras for various deities, I found that, only one of the many mantras that Goddess Bhuvaneswari have, has this bija Krom .. which other mantras you have found this bija in?

Comment: sriman,thanks for enlightening me. i have not seen  or i am not aware of any other mantras which has this Krom bija except Goddess Bhuvaneswari has!!! dhanysomi !!!Great to hear that, you have mentioned Goddess Bhuvaneswari... i have observed that, in one grantha, they used "tryakshari". In those "tryakshari" moola mantras, they mentioned one moolamantra with "Krom" !!!                     
  Can I start jaap using this Bija,without Guru initiation?

Comment: Tantras will say only after initiation you can do the japa .. however, if u are initiated into any other mantras then u can do .. but do u know the rishi-chandah-devata of the mantra u want to chant? knowing those is imp too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Goddess Mahatripura Sundari holds several weapons like bow, arrow, pAsha and ankusha.

Now, all of these weapons have corresponding Bija mantrik representations. And, among those, KROM is the Bija for the Ankusha (goad).

> TuriyamarunAvargAd dvitiyamapi pArvati |
>  Pumstri kodandayugalam
>   **kAmohagnir vyApakohankushah ||**
>
> O PArvati, The 4th alphabet of the Ta-varga, Dha (i.e. Dham with bindu
>   added) and the 2nd, Tha (i.e. Tham), are respectively, the Dhanu-bija
>   (bija for the bows) for KAmeswara and KAmeswari; **and Krom is the
>   ankusha-bija for both.**
>
> **NityA ShodashikArnava Tantram 4.66**

Here Pum=KAmeswara and Stri=KAmeswari or Goddess LalitA. Note that Ankusha etc are held by KAmeswara and KAmeswari both.

Decoding the mantra can be done like as below:

KamohagnirvyApakah ---- KAmah=Ka; Agni=ref (Ra); vyApakah=O, thus we get Kro; now Bindu (m) is to be added at the top/end.

Also, additionally, Dham is the Dhanu-bija for KAmeswara where as Tham the same for KAmeswari.

These Bijas are useful during Ayudha Puja (pujas done to the weapons).

Comment: Nice answer.We in bengal use the mantra with Ankusha-mudra for jala-suddhi. BTW, K is vaayava-varna repesenting Marut-tattva, R is Aagneya-varna representing Agni-tattva, O is parthiva-varna representing kshiti-tattva and M is vyoma-varna representing vyoma-tattva, according to the Sarada-Tilaka. And for Anga-nyasa of Kalipuja, KROM is used with KRAAM and KROUM etc for example.

Comment: Yes I know about that classification of alphabets according to panchabhutas .. it is used during Diksha for the Kulakula Chakra consideration @Partha

Comment: its krom or kraum ?

Comment: Krom ... @RakeshJoshi

Comment: You will find it as bija mantra for Vajreshvari Nitya in Shri Vidya cult.

Answer (score 0):

It's also the Beej Mantra of Krodh Bhairav
bija of Krodhisha (krodha = anger, isha = lord), the one who has conquered anger.
It's thought of as anger Beej but it's not.
Krodh isha means Lord of anger, means who has won over anger
Lalita Sahasranama p. 74: Ka stands for joy and fame; ra is considered as powerful as it is the bija of agni, the fire; ma stands for comforts in the present and future births. The repeated chanting of krom will give all-round prosperity and happiness.
Swamiji: Ka is the cause, Ra is the mind, O is the energy of the subtle sound, M is perfection.
Mahashodashimantra: Symbolizes Kroda Bhairava, the consort of Chinamasta. the sixth Maha Vidya .

Comment: Welcome to HSE! It’s a nice answer. Hope to see you becoming an avid user. Since you’ve just joined, you can have a look at [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions) along with the citation policy; and at highly voted recent answers by other users. For more help on site functioning you can contact our moderator Naruto in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) one you have sufficient reputation of 20.